# Android: one activity in two of four flavors

Tags: android

I have an Activity which is only used in **two of four** different flavors. Is it possible to use flavors in Android so that this activity is only assigned to two of the flavors?

Comment: Can you be more specific? From what I understand you have an Activity class and 4 Gradle Flavor. You want this Activity visible only in some of the Flavors? Is that right?

Comment: Correct. 2 of the flavors should see the Activity, the other two not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a custom source files location for each flavor. For example

```
productFlavors {
    flavor2 {
    }
    flavor1 {
    }
}

sourceSets{
    main {
    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
 }

flavor2 {
    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest-flavor2.xml'
    res.srcDirs = ['res-flavor2', 'res']
    java.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/java','src/java']
}

flavor1 {
    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    java.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/java','src/java']
}
```

But while this is possible, **I strongly advice you to avoid this approach** because if you would like to import some features from one flavor to another, then the import part will be a hell.

Also this might bring lots of complexity to the code, because you might get end up creating lots of `if (flavor1)... else if (flavor2)..` code that is not easy to maintain.

A simple solution, is always the best. So consider the following.

1. Split your architecture into [submodules](https://gist.github.com/daniellevass/2c46cf33e3814e685b47). Your main module will have the common code inside.
2. Create libray modules for different features you want to add.
3. Use Git [repositories](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) and [branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) for each module, in order to have increase control and backup for changes

I hope that this will give you a starting point on creating a maintainable structure.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. But this actually means my requirement can not be satisfied. With your solution I can assign ActivityA to flavor1 and flavor2 (mis)using the same flavor java.srcDirs (so that flavor3 and flavor4 are not seeing ActivityA). Do you agree?

Comment: With the answer I suggested not to be used, the flavor1 and 2 might point to the same structure and flavor 3 and 4 to others. Don't forget that you can always point to directories with sub directories, and common classes be in one of the super directories so they are available. On the other hand, having git repositories and submodules will gently solve your issues in an elegant matter.